# How to include gtkmm in my program for the users?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

im currently building an application that uses gtkmm and when i brought it to a friend and wanted to test it on hist computer it did not work because the gtkmm version he had installed was too low. I have read online that it is possible and covered by the license that you can include gtkmm (binaries?) within your program and let it use that version, so that it is compatible on all systems. But I dont know how to do that, can you help me with it?

THanks in advance for the answers :)

Comment: So, this probably means you can distribute _library files_ (e.g. `lib.dylib` for macOS, `lib.dll` for Windows and so on) alongside your program. You could also try linking the lib statically (you should obtain the `lib.a` file somehow for this).

Comment: Yes thats probably what I mean :D Linking statically seems not to be an option as it is prohibited by gtk license. But how would I tell the programm to use the library file instead of the already installed gtkmm?

Comment: as far as I know, the program will always try to load the 'nearest' library file (which, BTW, can be a serious security flaw as anybody could use some malicious lib file, and then the program will use it, thus effectively executing whatever (malicious?) functions the fake lib provides), e.g. the one in the same directory, so you can put the lib inside the same directory the executable resides in.

Comment: ok thanks thats what i wanted to know :D This seems like a very strange mechanism though, i agree.